# Local variable 'qstIndex' can't be referenced before it is declared issue

Tags: flutter, dart, local-variables

Local variable 'qstIndex' can't be referenced before it is declared.
Try moving the declaration to before the first use, or renaming the local variable so that it doesn't hide a name from an enclosing scope.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  var qstIndex = 0;
  void selectedanswer() {
    var qstIndex = qstIndex + 1;
    print('Answer selected');
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var questions = [
      'what color ?',
      'what fav food',
    ];
```

tried possible ways to solve this issue seeking help if anyone can help with this.

Answer (score 0):

In the line

```
var qstIndex = qstIndex + 1;
```

The compiler will treat `qstIndex` as a local variable, hence it is not declared yet. Just remove the var to extend the scope.

```
var qstIndex = 0;
  void selectedanswer() {
    qstIndex = qstIndex + 1;
    print('Answer selected');
  }
```

Comment: thank you so much , I don't know how I didn't notice! ‍♀️‍♀️